# Can a python 3.9 program compiled with pyinstaller run on Windows 7?

Tags: python, python-3.x, windows, pyinstaller

I am making some software in python 3.9.7. It is for someone that is not very tech-savvy and is running windows 7. I understand that Python 3.9 is incompatible with windows 7. However, I intend to compile it to exe using pyinstaller. Since all error messages in pyinstaller exes say the name of the source script, I am wondering if you can actually run a python 3.9 compiled exe on Windows 7.

Preferably I would not like to reinstall python as an old version.

Comment: pyinstaller doesn't "compile" a python project. It packages it as a distributable executable, but it is still reliant on the same old CPython runtime

Comment: So yes I can run a python 3.9 exe on Windows 7?

Comment: I have no idea. Apparently, there is pre-compiled CPython runtime available on the official website for 3.9. That being said, there may be some out there. Have you tried to see if this works?

Comment: No, Python 3.9 is incompatible with Windows 7. PyInstaller doesn't change that. It _might_ work, but it's not supported.

Comment: Sorry, to correct my last comment, apparently, the precompiled CPython 3.9 interpreters available on the official website **do not** support Windows 7.